# Blazes not swimming up in lava

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to build a blaze farm, and I've noticed that blazes aren't swimming up in lava. I'm in version 14w26c. I did some testing in a creative world, and it seems in version 1.7.9 they do, but 14w26c they dont.

Is this a bug in the snapshot, or is this something intended by Mojang?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been a bug, as notified by the [bug tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-49937) since 14w08a, and has not been fixed. Snapshots are buggy.

Comment: Ahh, I thought it might be a bug. I've got a work around for my farm until this get fixed then :). Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

It seems like it's a bug since at least 14w08a according to this bug report: [link](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-48907)

Comment: That's a link to a Facebook image :p